# My Bloch sphere/ qsphere is appearing as an ellipse/oval

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I tried to plot a Bloch vector. However, my Bloch sphere is appearing as an ellipse/oval instead of a circle. I am having the same issues with qsphere also. [image] instead of [image: this]

```
from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_vector

%matplotlib inline

plot_bloch_vector([0,1,0], title="New Bloch Sphere")
```

Comment: An issue has been opened for this problem: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/4770. It looks like it might be an issue with a specific matplotlib version

Comment: Thank You. I changed my version of Matplotlib from 3.3.0 to 3.2.2 and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: [Qiskit Terra 0.16](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-terra/0.16) (release Oct 2020) fixes this issue.

I just merged [PR 4893](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/4893), fixing this issue in <s>coming</s> Qiskit Terra 0.16. This closes [4905](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/4905) and [4893](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/4893) (reporting this very same problem) by setting the correct aspecting ration when Matplotlib installed is 3.3.0 or above. This issue was introduced by Matplotlib 3.3 as part of [a fix](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/users/whats_new.html#axes3d-no-longer-distorts-the-3d-plot-to-match-the-2d-aspect-ratio).

**TL;DR**: Problem introduce by MPL 3.3.0 that will be fixed in Qiskit Terra 0.16. In the meanwhile, you can downgrade to MPL 3.2 as a workaround.